# Find element in multi layer pages for single website

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, python, test-strategy

I want to scrape this marketplace data https://www.tokopedia.com/search?st=shop&q=dapur

but to get the data, that I want, I must go through pass some layers in the page.

In this case this web have `3 layers`, 1st layer is the shop catalogue or the Starting `URL` page:

(in this page users must click the `Lihat Toko` button to go to the next layer):

[image]

2nd layer, is the `Shop profile`
(In this page users must click the `Info Toko` button to go to the final layer/pop up content):

[image]

Final layer, is the pop up content.  I want to get the data from this pop up box:

[image]

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_path = r"E:\Chromedriver\chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)

driver.get("https://www.tokopedia.com/search?st=shop&q=dapur")

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="css-gmuwbf"]//button[1]').click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="css-ais6tt"]//button[3]').click()
```

I've run the code, but always have an error messages.

Comment: Agung, please show the exact error messages you are receiving. Most likely you have problem of waits, because the page has AJAX behavior between clicks.

Additionally, Selenium may not be the necessary tool for this; have you consider simply making calls to the Tokopedia API? https://developer.tokopedia.com/openapi/guide/#/shop/

Comment: the error message:

Comment: NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class="css-ais6tt"]//button[3]"}
  (Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.89)

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to switch the window first then only you will be navigate to the second-page (layer):

please use below piece of code to switch your window :

```
public boolean switchToWindow(String windowname) 
    {
        
        Set<String> windowsname=driver.getWindowHandles();
        try {
        windowsname.forEach(window->{
            if(window.equalsIgnoreCase(windowname))
            {
                 driver.switchTo().window(window);
                 
            }
        });
        return true;
        }
        catch(NoSuchWindowException e)
        {
            return false;
        }
        
    }
```

now please use the below piece of code to switch the alert and get the UIData :

```
public String getAlertData()
    {
        try {
        WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
        Alert alert =driver.switchTo().alert();
        return alert.getText(); 
        }
        catch(NoAlertPresentException e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```